# MySQL Windows 10: Does Windows 32 and 64 bit platforms require specific DLL?

Tags: mysql, delphi, dll

I've created a testing program to check for an error accessing the MySQL database and realized that when compiling the program on Win32 platform and then on Win64, it was necessary to use one DLL for 32 bit platform and another one DLL for 64 bit platform to access the same database.

Are these two different DLLs (one for 32 bits and one for 64 bits) really needed? Can't you access the same database by using only one DLL?

Comment: 32-bit executables need 32-bit DLLs and 64-bit executables need 64-bit DLLs.

Comment: Ok. That's what I concluded too, but I thought there might be an alternative. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your need a DLL with same platform bit size as the main application. This is imposed by Windows not Delphi: A 32 bit application cannot call a 64 bit DLL and a 64 bit application cannot call a 32 bit DLL. Speaking MySQL, this means you need the correct DLL as you have noticed.

Comment: Ok. That's what I concluded too, but I thought there might be an alternative. Thanks.

Comment: @wBB There are third party providers of Delphi data access components that offer as a feature direct connection to some databases (no need for client DLLs).  One example for MySQL would be Devart and their [MySQL Data Access Components (MyDAC)](https://www.devart.com/mydac/)

Comment: Nice! I'll check. Thanks.